# AWS ECS - Invalid or Corrupt Jar File

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, jar, amazon-ecs

i am trying to deploy an spring boot executable jar. 
If I push the code to github, github actions build the docker container and push it to ecr.
ECS shows me an

```
Error: Invalid or corrupt jar file.
```

I did it the same way with 4 other application and it worked. Only this one doesnt work.
If I run it locally, it works fine.

The different to the other projects is that the jar is bigger than 100 MB and muss be pushed with 
git LFS.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the github workflow. It was incorrect, so the jar was copied wrong.